# Javascript innerHTML updating issue

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have the following JavaScript line:

```
<div id="box" name="1" margin="4px" padding="4px" onclick="memory(1)"></div>
```

With the associated `memory()` function being:

```
function memory(a) {
    var tmpDar = a-1;
    var m = document.getElementsByName(tmpDar);
    m.innerHTML = arrA[tmpDar];

}
```

However, when I try executing the code, the HTML doesn't alter... Can somebody please help me?

Comment: What are the contents of `arrA`?

Comment: And Do you really have an element named `0`? (tmpDar) I think probably not.  Your `getElementsByName(tmpDar)` looks to be faulty.

Comment: arrA is dynamically populated with random numbers between 0 and 999 using another function

Comment: Did you define the script in your html page within the <script></script> tag?

Comment: @user1394965 I cannot use id as I use id as a reference to the stylesheet to style the div

Comment: You can still use id's even if they are being used in your stylesheet. The fact that they are being referenced in your style sheet has no bearing of if you can or can't use id's in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

[`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) returns a NodeList and not a single element!

So in order to set the `innerHTML` of your div, you have to reference an entry inside that array, e.g., like this:

```
function memory(a) {
    var tmpDar = a-1;
    var m = document.getElementsByName(tmpDar);
    m[0].innerHTML = arrA[tmpDar];
}
```

In your code you set the `innerHTML` property for the NodeList object, which has no (visual) effect in the document.

In general it would be better to use `id` instead of `name`. Then you could use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) in a way like this:

```
function memory(a) {
    var tmpDar = a-1;
    var m = document.getElementById(tmpDar);
    m.innerHTML = arrA[tmpDar];
}
```

Comment: Damned! You have been just faster than me :)

Comment: Still, look at the value of `tmpDar`. Does that look like an id or element name?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Wondering about numbers for name attributes, too. But the only reference I found was [this](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fe-name), which allows any "non-empty value" for the name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

your trying to find all elements with a name of `0` as far as I can tell. And there is no `0` name.

Also what the other two said, it returns an array you need to call an index on that array.

Comment: It's `getElementsByName()`, not `getElementsByTagName()`, but still, the name attribute is unlikely to be `tmpDar`'s value 0

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName` returns an array. So if the element that you want is unique with this name, you should replace your code by :

```
function memory(a) {
    var tmpDar = a-1;
    var m = document.getElementsByName(tmpDar);
    m[0].innerHTML = arrA[tmpDar];  // Here I have added index 0
}
```